# Video Analysis Tool - Open Source Software Recommendation

Tags: software-recommendation, streaming

This is blurring the lines between programming and vid production (question not allowed on Stack Overflow or Programmers)

I am throwing this out there as I know there may not be a suitable solution, but if there is maybe someone here may be able to help.

My team is brainstorming a video stream analysis tool - essentially something that would be able to test media streams and provide analytics about that stream (bitrate, packet loss,startup time etc), preferably this is a tool that could be run in the background on Linux and accept tests as they come in - perhaps fed from a third party API.

If you are familiar with WebPageTest then essentially i would be looking for something like this, but for media streams (GUI is not required).

We would prefer python but that is not a requirement.

I have seen pymedia - but it seems quite old, and maybe not a good fit.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that can be achieved with [ffprobe](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html).

You can see example of getting json format from it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708373/get-ffmpeg-information-in-friendly-way)

Comment: mediainfo https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download is also not bad for this task